# data-icons not showing in online app

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile app for iPad using HTML, Javascript, CSS, and jQuery Mobile. I have popups with the black close (x) icons in the upper right hand corner of the popups. Everything works fine on desktop iPad simulator using safari browser. I click a button/link, and a popup fires, displaying the icon in the upper right hand corner. When I publish to my website, and view on my iPad, Safari browser, (1st generation), the close (x) icon disappears, the container for the icon is there, just no icon. I have checked, and all the files uploaded to my server correctly... anyone have any ideas here? thanks for any help!

Comment: Please share code/link/[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) atleast.

Comment: sorry, http://www.webwrinkle.com/ on FAQs page

Comment: You must put image for jquery in css folder did you those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your server [image: Problem is with your server]

[Icon file](http://www.webwrinkle.com/css/images/icons-18-black.png) gives Internal Server Error

Comment: I am testing through a MAMP stack on my desktop, any idea why it would run fine on desktop server and not when I publish on my web server? Sorry, I should have tested this earlier...

Comment: There's probably some issue with your server. Try contacting host/server provider.